# Is the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\le1\}$ connected?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\le1\}$ connected?

Please help me. I'm clueless.

Added: Is the set convex?

Comment: I can see it's not convex since $(1,0),(0,1)$ are in the set but $(.5,.5)$ is not.

Comment: HINT: Show that it is star shaped.

Comment: That would be harder @asatzhh.

Comment: No, star shaped is a great way to attack the problem.

Comment: What is $x^{2/3}$ when $x\leq0$?

Answer (score 8):

If $(x, y)$ is in the set, then so are the points $(kx, ky)$ for all $0 \le k \le 1$. That is, the line to the origin. So the set is connected.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$B_{2/3}\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\le 1\}$ is equivalently the set 
\begin{align*}
B_{2/3} &= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid |x|^{2/3}+|y|^{2/3}\le 1\} = \{ {x}\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \lVert {x} \rVert_{2/3}^{2/3} \leq 1 \} \\
&= \{ {x}\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \lVert {x} \rVert_{2/3} \leq 1 \}
\end{align*}
that is the unit ball for a $p$-norm (where $p\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{2}{3}$). This should settle the problem of whether it is connected.

PS: you can see what it looks like on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_.3C_p_.3C_1).